# If Statement SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swiftui

I have an if statement in my SwiftUI view VStack to toggle an integer which stops a SQLite database from being created more than once, but I'm given numerous errors, stopping the code from building. The variable (appInfo.toggleswitch is an integer set to 0 by default in a class, which I subscribe to in this view using a environment object)

```
        if appInfo.toggleswitch == 0 {
            let db = DBHelper()
            $appInfo.toggleswitch = 1 }
```

Comment: Share those "numerous errors" please. Did you try without `$`?

Comment: In view you work only with view, ie... there should be view in `if` statement, if you need some model calculations then do it in model.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write code like this in a View. SwiftUI only render UI.
I would do something like this:

```
Toggle(isOn: $appInfo.toggleswitch.onChange(myFunction)) {
    YourView() 
} 

func myFunction() {
    let db = DBHelper()
    appInfo.toggleswitch = 1
}
```